# template cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead

Tags: vue.js

I want to implement the image preview function，Use the image component in the View Design frame,this error occurs.
The Component url is [enter link description here](https://www.iviewui.com/view-ui-plus/component/view/image),Example 5。
The code is shown below：

```
<template>
    <Space wrap>
        <template v-for="(url, index) in urlList" :key="url">
            <Image :src="url" fit="contain" width="120px" height="80px" preview :preview-list="urlList" :initial-index="index" />
        </template>
    </Space>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                urlList: [
                    'https://file.iviewui.com/images/image-demo-1.jpg',
                    'https://file.iviewui.com/images/image-demo-2.jpg',
                    'https://file.iviewui.com/images/image-demo-3.jpg',
                    'https://file.iviewui.com/images/image-demo-4.jpg',
                    'https://file.iviewui.com/images/image-demo-5.jpg',
                    'https://file.iviewui.com/images/image-demo-6.jpg'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't loop over *template* tag. Instead, do an iteration on *img* tag.

Answer (score 2):

`<template>` tags are removed when the component renders. That's why you should pass `key` attribute to the child element (which is real).

```
<template v-for="(url, index) in urlList">
  <Image :key="url" :src="url" />
</template>
```

You can also use v-for directly on `<Image>`

```
<Image 
  v-for="(url, index) in urlList" 
  :key="url" 
  :src="url" 
/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I tried the two methods you mentioned, but the preview effect could not be achieved.  Could you please help me to see if these two methods are effective?